# how to deploy an azure openai services

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I have azure open ai service, I added the docs and tried to deploy it as web app
but when I try to use the Api, I get different result and when I close the OpenAI studio I didn't find and data resources
[image]

I tried to deploy this document to web app.
it works from web app and the chat playground. but when I try to use the Api to call the OpenAI azure.